# Dependency not loaded in library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

In my current application I can load correctly a dependency if I declare it in the gradle file of the application. Instead, If I declare it in the library, it doesn't work anymore. Any reason why this is happening?

I'm trying to add the following line:

```
compile 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.2.0'
```

Application gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("../[...].jks")
            storePassword "[...]"
            keyAlias "[...]"
            keyPassword "[...]"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':gsd_droid_common:GsdDroidApplicationLib')
    //compile 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.2.0'
}
```

While the library is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':gsd_droid_common:DroidLib')
    compile project(':gsd_droid_common:OtpServiceLib')
    compile project(':gsd_droid_common:viewpagerindicator')
    compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0'
    compile 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.2.0'
}
```

This is the settings.gradle file instead:

```
include ':fundus:GsdDroid'
include ':fundus:CentervueLauncher'
include ':fundus:StartHomeActivity'
include ':perimeter:GsdDroid'
include ':perimeter:CentervueLauncher'
include ':perimeter:StartHomeActivity'
include ':gsd_droid_common:DroidLib'
include ':gsd_droid_common:GsdDroidLib'
include ':gsd_droid_common:GsdSetup'
include ':gsd_droid_common:GsdConfigurator'
include ':gsd_droid_common:External:ErlangOTP'
include ':gsd_droid_common:External:volley'
include ':gsd_droid_common:External:DroidPlot'
include ':gsd_droid_common:External:datetimepicker'
include ':gsd_droid_common:CentervueLauncherUserRoleIO'
include ':gsd_droid_common:CentervueLauncherBroadcast'
include ':gsd_droid_common:UsbTethering'
include ':gsd_droid_common:OtpService'
include ':gsd_droid_common:OtpServiceLib'
include ':gsd_droid_common:viewpagerindicator'
include ':gsd_droid_common:smoothaccordion'
project(':gsd_droid_common:smoothaccordion').projectDir =
        new File('gsd_droid_common/External/smoothaccordion')
include ':gsd_droid_common:GsdDroidApplicationLib'
project(':gsd_droid_common:GsdDroidApplicationLib').projectDir =
        new File('gsd_droid_common/GsdDroidApplicationLib')
include ':gsd_droid_common:Logcatudp'
project(':gsd_droid_common:Logcatudp').projectDir =
        new File('gsd_droid_common/External/logcatudp')
include ':gsd_droid_common:Snowdon'
project(':gsd_droid_common:Snowdon').projectDir =
            new File('gsd_droid_common/External/snowdon')
```

Any idea?

Comment: can u explain it little more ? you are added a new module or ?

Comment: I've edited the post, btw I wanted to add the library: 
    compile 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.2.0'

Comment: can u publish the code in the settings.gradle of ur application

Comment: Add compile 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.2.0' also in the project. Using a local library the project doesn't use the nested dependencies.

Comment: It might solve the problem in the application, but I need to access to the dependency both in the application and in the library, and I can't do it in the library anyway :( @Nithinlal: done

Comment: @Filnik if you need in app and library you have to add the same dependency in both the module.
Otherwise you have to use an maven dependency.

Comment: ah ok. I didn't know that. However, if I add to both of them, I can see the dependency only in the application and not in the library. So it's still not loading the dependency there and I cannot see the reason why :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed this post by Gabriele Mariotti: http://gmariotti.blogspot.it/2015/07/how-to-centralize-support-libraries.html

Still not working.

Clean all project, File/Invalidate cache and restart. Restart of the computer.

Still nothing...

...then I tried to build the project. And magic happends. I don't know why, but until you don't build it, it doesn't reload the dependencies (or whatever, I don't know, but now it's working).